# Algorithm to pick a single value from a vector in matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vector

I have a vector of equiprobable values. Let's say:

```
 [ 12.62       22.856       22.983       23.111       24.295]
```

I have to pick a single value among these values. In this case, in my opinion, I would exclude 12.62. Then the mean value among the remaining (22.856 22.983 23.111 24.295) is 23.311. I think 23.111 should be a good choice between these equiprobable values. When considering a general vector of arbitrary values and dimension which criterion/algorithm should I use to pick a single value inside the considered vector?

Comment: This cannot be answered in general, as it will heavily depend on the use-case for which you're picking the scalar from the vector.

Comment: So vector of arbitrary values is an input to your function, but I don't know from your question what you expect it to return?

Comment: Why is 12.62 excluded?  Before you continue with this, ask yourself why you think 12.62 should be excluded, then generalize on that, then add this to your question.  It'll attract more attention as it will be better formulated.

Comment: @kostek The output should be a scalar value, according to some criterion, of the input vector.

Comment: @Kevin - Yeah.  What's this criterion?

Comment: I'm tempted to write an answer in the style of http://xkcd.com/221/ :-P

Comment: @rayryeng 12.62 seems an outlier...

Comment: @Kevin - Why is an outlier?

Comment: @Kevin - If it is your intent to ask for a suitable criterion for mapping a vector to a singular value, you're opening a can of worms.  You could use any [vector norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) for example, or any [statistical measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_statistics).  There are simply too many - each with their advantages and disadvantages.  A better question to ask yourself is **why** you want to do this, then from there we can figure stuff out.  For now, I've flagged your question as primarily opinion-based because it is... until we know more.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes I'm asking a suitable criterion for mapping a vector to a singular value... Any examples?

Comment: So ... is you actual question how to identify outliers?

Comment: @das-g I found a possible solution I assumed that outliers are more than two standard deviations from the median, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
vector=[ 12.62       22.856       22.983       23.111       24.295];  
all_idx = 1:length(vector);
outlier_idx = abs(vector- median(vector)) > 2*std(vector);
vector=vector(~outlier_idx);
val = mean(vector);
tmp = abs(vector-val);
[v, idx] = min(tmp);
vector(idx)
```

This code returns 23.111, I assumed that outliers are more than two standard deviations from the median..

Comment: This is completely different from what you asked before.  Your question now seems like you want to remove outliers then compute a statistic based on what is remaining.  Your question does not explicitly state that and leaves it to the imagination to figure that out.

Comment: Don't mean to sound harsh, but perhaps next time you ask a question you should probably lay out what exactly it is you want to do rather than leave it in the open for us to figure it out.

Comment: @rayryeng I posted a question with an example asking a criterion to generalize over my example. das-g understood the question and posted a helpful answer according to the question. Probably I had to post to Cross Validated. Have a nice day.

Comment: To get to that point, he had to figure it out for himself.  It wasn't so obvious for other people like me... but I digress.  Take care.

Comment: Indeed, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30606263/674064) is based almost completely on guesswork. :-( I guess I was lucky. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to read (i.e., guess) from your question and from the comments so far what criteria you're implicitly already applying. I came up with these:

- The vector shall be mapped to one of its elements.
- Outliers amongst the elements shall neither be candidates nor influence which of the other elements is chosen.
- The mean of the candidates shall be in some way relevant to what candidate is chosen.

with these criteria, one can come up with the following algorithm:

1. Identify outliers (criteria of what constitutes an outlier to be determined)
2. Remove outliers
3. Compute mean of remaining values
4. Choose the one of the remaining values closest to that mean

Off course there are infinitely many other algorithms that'd also satisfy the identified criteria, with varying meaningfulness and varying applicability to different use-cases. And off course, again depending on the actual use-case, the criteria I identified might or might not be the correct generalization of what you did.

Answer (score 1):

> When considering a general vector of arbitrary values and dimension which criterion/algorithm should I use to pick a single value inside the considered vector?

It depends what you want.

It can be `mean(input_vector)` or `norm(input_vector)`.

You should first ask yourself what you want this scalar value to be/represent.